# How to divide two dfs with dissimilar column length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
lines

+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2 |   line amount#3 |   line amount#4 |   line amount#5 |
|----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|  0 |             250 |          250    |           250   |          250    |             250 |
|  1 |             250 |          250    |           250   |          250    |             250 |
|  2 |              14 |            7.35 |             9.9 |           27.75 |             nan |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+








perc
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   btw-percentage#1 |   btw-percentage#2 |   btw-percentage#3 |   btw-percentage#4 |   btw-percentage#5 |   btw-percentage#6 |
|--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------|
|                10  |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |
|                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |
|                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |                nan |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+




update  = lines.to_numpy() / perc.to_numpy()
```

when dividing I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,6)
```

Which is logical since the columns are not the same shape.

I want to trim the column shape of the perc column based on the length of the lines column. So that would become #5. Is this possible with numpy?
desired output after division:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2 |   line amount#3 |   line amount#4 |   line amount#5 |
|----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|  0 |             25  |          250    |           250   |          250    |             250 |
|  1 |             250 |          250    |           250   |          250    |             250 |
|  2 |              14 |            7.35 |             9.9 |           27.75 |             nan |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for x, y in zip(lines.columns, perc.columns):
    lines[x] = lines[x] / perc[y].fillna(1)
```

Comment: This worked even better, adding for the possibility of varying columns. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let us try with `np.divide`

```
np.divide(lines, perc.iloc[:, :lines.shape[1]].fillna(1))
```

In case the order and number of columns is not fixed then we can filter the common columns by using `Index.intersection`

```
c1 = lines.columns.str.replace('line amount', 'btw-percentage')
c2 = c1.intersection(perc.columns, sort=False)

np.divide(lines.loc[:, c1.isin(c2)], perc[c2].fillna(1))
```

---

```
   line amount#1  line amount#2  line amount#3  line amount#4  line amount#5
0           25.0         250.00          250.0         250.00          250.0
1          250.0         250.00          250.0         250.00          250.0
2           14.0           7.35            9.9          27.75            NaN
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! This is working excellently

Comment: @Max Happy coding!

Comment: KeyError: "['btw-amount#7', 'btw-amount#9', 'btw-amount#10', 'btw-amount#8'] not in index"

Comment: When trying to add columns is your second solution possible as well?

Comment: @Max We need to take intersection of columns. Check `c = lines.columns.str.replace('line amount', 'btw-percentage').intersection(perc.columns, sort=False)`

Comment: @Max Is the order of columns fixed in both the dataframes? And do you need to divide only the common columns in both dataframes which corresponds with each other?

Comment: Order is not fixed unfortunately.. Only the common columns need to be divided indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
update = np.divide(lines.to_numpy(), np.delete(perc.to_numpy(), lines.shape, axis=1))
```